# FCM push notification not received when app is closed in background- Flutter android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) . My problem is: FCM push notification is not received by the device when the app is closed in recent tabs.
It works fine when the app is in foreground or in background. But, When I closed it from background , I didn't receive any notification in the notification tray.

I saw many post and tried many solutions, but nothing works in my case :(

Steps I've tried :

1. I've added fcm in dependencies & applied google plugin in my build.gradle
   here's my `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.myapplication.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
}
```

2.I've added google-services dependecy in my project/build.gradle
Here's my `project/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

3. setting android:enabled="true" & android:exported="true" in manifest.xml
   Here's my `app/src/main/Manifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:label="partner_location_project"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
   ....
   ....
   ....
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Here's my dart file where i've declared FCM.

```
class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  void fcm_listener() async {
    try {
      var token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("fcm token = $token");
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onLaunch $message");
        },
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage $message");
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onResume $message");
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("fcm exception");
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fcm_listener();
  }
```

Any ideas are appreciated!!

Comment: What device are you using for testing? Can you post what is the content of your push notification?

Comment: I am testing it on real device (realme 6 pro)

Comment: Realme has a "battery saving feature" that blocks intents to an app that is closed.
Try following the steps shown at https://dontkillmyapp.com/realme, find the App battery management and allow at least auto start for your app.

Comment: @JoãoPauloSena Tried your method now, But, it also didn't work 
. Anyway for your response. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: That is weird... Can you post your push notification data? Also, can you try to investigate the logcat and check if the intent is being delivered to your app?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am also facing the same issue in oppo device.